# How to cycle list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I begin with the following list `[a,b,c]`, and that I from this list want to create the following list `[[a,b,c], [c,a,b], [b,c,a]]`which contains all the cycles of the original list. How can I do that in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: you try something ?

Comment: I could define a function that rotates a list
`
def rotate(l, n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]`
but to me it seem like there should be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Are you just looking for permutations of a list? Cycling typically refers to something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with `list comprehension` or you want something special ?

```
lst = ['a','b','c']

n_lst = [lst[x:] + lst[:x] for x in range(len(lst))]
print(n_lst)
```

**Output**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['c', 'a', 'b']]
```

Something special for all peremutations

```
import itertools
list(itertools.permutations(lst))
```

**Output**

```
[
  ('a', 'b', 'c'), 
  ('a', 'c', 'b'), 
  ('b', 'a', 'c'), 
  ('b', 'c', 'a'), 
  ('c', 'a', 'b'), 
  ('c', 'b', 'a')
]
```

Also i check the time of execution of a `list comprehension` and of build-in function `rotate` from `collections.deque` object from @jpp answer.

```
lst = list(range(10000))

# list comprehension time
1.923051118850708

# rotate from collections.deque time
1.6390318870544434
```

[rotate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) is faster

Answer (score 3):

Using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and its method `rotate`:

```
from collections import deque

A = deque(['a', 'b', 'c'])

res = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    A.rotate()
    res.append(list(A))

print(res)

[['c', 'a', 'b'],
 ['b', 'c', 'a'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```